# Apache Camel sftp delay query parameter doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, apache-camel

This is the code from my Route configuration method

```
from("sftp://{{sftp.source-url}}?username={{sftp.username}}&password={{sftp.password}}
&delay=5000")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "here here");
```

from the logs, I can see that 'here here' gets logged every 15ish seconds

```
2020-10-11 12:18:21,512 INFO  [route1] (Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - here here
2020-10-11 12:18:38,016 INFO  [route1] (Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - here here
2020-10-11 12:18:57,219 INFO  [route1] (Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - here here
2020-10-11 12:19:16,244 INFO  [route1] (Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - here here
```

I tried setting the delay to 1 minute, but code logs at the same intervals of 15ish seconds

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many files in the folder when the test begin?

Comment: Its working fine, the log is only when there is a file to download. You can enable DEBUG/TRACE logging and see the ftp consumer is running every 5h sec or what the delay is.

Also tell us what version of Camel you are using? And as always try with latest patch release / latest version etc.

Comment: @ClausIbsen thank you for your response
There is always a file to download, this sftp has a lot of files (at least 50) and gets updated constantly. I would like it to check for files and download every 1hr for example
I'm using camel-quarkus 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml add this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

and try this :

```
from("sftp://{{sftp.username}}@{{sftp.source-url}}?password={{sftp.password}}&amp;delay=5000")
```

Comment: Doesn't work, throws an error:
`There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{amp;delay=5000}]`

Comment: delete "amp;" and put only & i mean &delay=5000

Comment: that's what I initially tried, see in my original example above in line 2:

`... &password={{sftp.password}}&delay=5000"...`